# Trigger monitor does not work

Tags: ibm-mq

I have created a queue manager (`IBM WebSphere MQ->QueueManagers->new->QueueManager`)

I have created a initiation Queue (`QueueManager->Queues->New->Local Queue`):

- Queue name: `INITQUEUE`
- Put Message & Get Message:`Allowed`
- Scope:`Queue manager`

I have created a process (`Process Definitions->New->Process Definition`):

- Process name:`Paint`
- Application Type:`DOS`
- Application ID:`C:\Users\Desktop\paint.bat`

I have created an application queue (`QueueManager->Queues->New->Local Queue`):

- Trigger type: `First`
- Trigger control: `On`
- Initiation queue: `INITQUEUE`
- Process name: `sample`

I have created a service to start the trigger monitor (`Services->New->Service`):

- service type: `server`
- service control : `Queue Manager`
- Start command: `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\runmqtrm`
- Start args: `-q INITQUEUE`

When a messages put to the application Queue, no trigger message is inserted into the initiation Queue.

When I start the trigger monitor, it automatically stops after few seconds.

How do I correct these issues.

This is the output got when I start the runmqtrm:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin>runmqtrm -m QMGR -q INITQUEUE 

5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2011.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.  
11/3/2017  01:54:43: WebSphere MQ trigger monitor started.  

__________________________________________________
11/3/2017  01:55:04: Waiting for a trigger message
```

There is no error in `AMQERR01.LOG`. But the process is not working.
Also when a data is inserted into Application queue, it is does not enable the initiation queue.
And in CMD it says as WebSphere MQ trigger monitor started,initiation queue's open input count increases to 1 but in my UI it still remains as stopped.

**Version of MQ server:**

```
Name:        WebSphere MQ  
Version:     7.5.0.2  
Level:       p750-002-130627  
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)  
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Windows  
Mode:        32-bit  
O/S:         Windows 7 Professional x64 Edition, Build 7601: SP1  
InstName:    Installation1  
InstDesc:  
Primary:     Yes  
InstPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ  
DataPath:    C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ  
MaxCmdLevel: 750  
AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.  
AMQ8351: WebSphere MQ Java environment has not been configured correctly.  

Name:        IBM WebSphere MQ custom channel for Windows Communication Foundatio
n  
Version:     7.5.0.2  
Level:       wn750-002-130611_P  
Build Type:  Production  

Name:        IBM Message Service Client for .NET (XMS .NET)  
Version:     2.5.0.2  
Level:       nn250-002-130627  
Build Type:  Production  

Name:        IBM Global Security Kit for WebSphere MQ  
Version:     8.0.14.28  
Build Type:  Production  
Mode:        32-bit  

Name:        IBM Global Security Kit for WebSphere MQ  
Version:     8.0.14.28  
Build Type:  Production  
Mode:        64-bit
```

Comment: Can you start the runmqtrm from a CMD prompt and then click edit and add the output to the end of the question.  Also look in the qmgrs/QmgrName/errors/AMQERR01.LOG to see if any errors happen at the same time you start the runmqtrm, if so add those as well.

Comment: Remember that trigger messages are not generated unless the trigger monitor is running. Fix the reason for the trigger monitor stopping soon after startup first, see Josh's comment.

Comment: please find the MQ server version above

Comment: Also note a few rules: 1. If you have a process reading from the Application queue a trigger message will not be generated. 2. With Trigger type: First, in general a trigger message is only generated when the depth of the queue increases from 0 to 1 and as @MoragHughson pointed out the trigger monitor is already connected to the INITQ.  So if the queue already had 1 message on it when you start the trigger monitor, MQ will not generate a trigger message.

Comment: I noted that your app queue you mention `Process name: sample`, but above that you say you created a process with `Process name:Paint`. These have to match so if this is how you have it setup it would not work you would need to point the app queue's process attribute to the name of the process you created.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the Process name and now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the configuration is that you created a Process called `Paint`, but on the application queue you set the Process name to `sample`.  The name of the process the queue points to needs to match the name of the process that you created..

---

Paul Clarke of [MQGem Software](http://www.mqgem.com/) presented a presentation at [Capitalware's MQ Technical Conference v2.0.1.4](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2014.html) called [MQ Triggering](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2014/MQ_Triggering.pdf) which is a comprehensive presentation on IBM MQ Triggering with details on how to troubleshoot issues that I have found very useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Process name: Paint

Silly rabbit, tricks are for kids!!

MQ is running under a service account.  You are trying launch a GUI application in the background.  I'm sure if you opened the Task Manager there will be many 'mspaint.exe' running but not visible.

Use a program that can run in the background or create your own.  Create a batch file called: hello.bat and put the following in it:

```
echo "Hello World. " %time% > C:\temp\hello.txt
```

Update the MQ Process definition with 'hello.bat' and do a test.  Note: Make sure the C:\temp directory exist.